# Visual Studio: debug information in release build

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, debug-symbols

I'm tempted to include debug information in my release builds that go out to customers.  As far as I see the only down side is 25% increase in the binary file size.  The advantage is that I can get an immediately usable crash dump, much easier to analyze.
I'm willing to live with the 25% increase.  Are there any other disadvantages I'm missing?

This is a C project and all I want to do is Linked/Debugging/Generate Debug Info

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The size of the executable should increase much less than 25%.

I'm actually a little surprised that it increases much at all, but some quick tests show that at least one large example project (ScummVM) increases the .exe from 10,205,184 bytes to 10,996,224 bytes just by adding the `/DEBUG` option to the link step (about an 8% increase). `/DEBUG` is specified using the `"Linker | Debugging | Generate Debug Info"` option in the IDE. Note that this settings *should* have no effect on the optimizations generated by the compiler.

I know that a pointer to the .pdb file is put in the executable, but there's not much to that. I experimented a bit and found that enabling the `/OPT:REF` linker option changed the size difference to 10,205,184 vs. 10,205,696. So the non `/DEBUG` build stayed the same size, but the `/DEBUG` build dropped to only 512 bytes larger (which could be accounted for by the pointer-to-.pdb - maybe the linker rounds to some multiple of 512 or something). Much less than 1% increase. Apparently, adding `/DEBUG` causes the linker to keep unreferenced objects unless you also specify `/OPT:REF`. (`"Linker | Optimization | References"` option in the IDE).

The program will run fine without the .pdb file - you can choose to send it to customers if you want to provide a better debugging experience at the customer site. If you just want to be able to get decent stack traces, you don't need to have the .pdb file on the customer machine - they (or some tool/functionality you provide) can send a dump file which can be loaded into a debugger at your site with the .pdb file available and get the same stack trace information port-mortem.

Of course, one thing to be aware of is that you'll need to archive the .pdb files along with your releases. The "Debugging Tools for Windows" package (which is now distributed in the Windows SDK) provides a symbol server tool so you can archive .pdb files and easily retrieve them for debugging.

The only drawback that I can think of to distributing .pdb files is that it can make reverse engineering your application easier, if that's a concern for you. Note that Microsoft distributes symbols for Windows (using a public symbol server - as well as packages of the full symbols sets for some specific releases). However, the symbols they distribute do get run through a sanitizing step that removes certain items they consider sensitive. You can do the same (or similar) using the linker's `/PDBSTRIPPED` option (`"Linker | Debugging | Strip Private Symbols"` in the IDE). See [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y87kw2fd.aspx) for details on what the option removes. If you're going to distribute symbols, it's probably appropriate to use that option.

Comment: Apparently, SCUMVM has very little unreferenced code :) After I enabled stripping unreferenced symbols the executable size returned to normal.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like /OPT:REF should be specified to remove unreferenced objects, not /OPT:NOREF. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx That's quite not intuitive for me...

Answer (score 2):

According to the Visual Studio 2005 documentation at *[Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)*:

> /DEBUG changes the defaults for the /OPT option from REF to NOREF and
>   from ICF to NOICF (so, you will need to explicitly specify /OPT:REF or
>   /OPT:ICF).

In my case it helped when I enabled both:

```
/O2 /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what language you're in, and there might be different answers for C++ vs. C#.

I'm not 100% sure what change you're considering making. Are you going to tell Visual Studio to make its standard Debug compile, and ship that, or are you going to edit a couple settings in the Release compile? A careful modification of a couple of settings in the Release build strikes me as the best approach.

Whatever you end up with, I'd make sure that optimizations are turned on, as that can make a significant difference in the performance of the compiled code.

Comment: But the other questions is... how do I make sure that optimizations are still in?  I mean, they are enabled, but what if "generate debug info" overrides the setting and disables them?

Comment: If you're in flat C, this setting is in the Property Pages for the project, under Configuration Properties::C/C++::Optimization. I believe the defaults are Optimization Disabled (/Od) for Debug builds, and Maximize Speed (/O2) for Release builds.

Comment: If you want to verify that the compiler setting took effect, pick a method, and look at the Debug and ModifiedRelease compiles in the disassembler. In Debug, you'll have a strong correlation between the C code and the assembly, in an optimized build things will be reearranged, and harder to follow. In theory, you could compare the ModifiedRelease assembly to the real Release assembly, and it should be the same, or at least closer than to the Debug assembly.

Answer (score -7):

I always send out the debug build, never the release build. I can't think of any disadvantages, and the advantages are as you mention.

Comment: Optimizations are useful things

Comment: @SLAks yeah, agree. I'm not making a debug build, but a release build with debug info... my understanding is that it still has all the optimizations, just some debug symbols also included.  Well, that's what I'm trying to clear out with this question.

Comment: Imagine a car dealer saying "I always sell lab prototypes, not the real car from the factory"... Oh, and you are probably not allowed to distribute the debug runtime to customers (IANAL, but have a look at the license for your compiler).