# Prevent my OS X app from asking users to install "XCode Command Line Developer Tools"

Tags: xcode, macos, mono, lldb

I created a Mac OS X app, and distribute it as a `.dmg` file.

I must have source code line numbers in stack traces, so I added `<DebugType>full</DebugType>` and `<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>` to my `.csproj` file ([not a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363991/visual-studio-debug-information-in-release-build) as I don't fear reverse engineering)

**PROBLEM:** Whenever a crash happen, apparently users are asked to install "XCode Command Line Developer Tools" to run "lldb" (debugger):

[image: XCode Command Line Developer Tools]

My program does not call this "lldb" thing in any way.
How can I **prevent this message** from getting displayed?
Users are office employees who have no idea what XCode is.

The app is [open source](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync) C# compiled using Monodevelop.

Having good stack traces with source code line numbers is very important, not something I want to give up.

Comment: Have you seen this article? I'm not really familiar with the subject but was curious so I searched and reading this seemed promising. http://dylanfoundry.org/2014/06/25/integrating-with-lldb/

Comment: @dcc: This article is about debugging with the "Dylan" programming language. It contains nothing about the message I asked about, right?

Comment: Is possible that one or more binaries or libraries that you're distributing are compiled as debug / develop, rather than release / deployment?

Comment: @Merlin069: Yes, please see my last paragraph. and the reason why.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, but I expect that this is the problem. I suggest you begin by confirming this by using Release builds.

Answer (score 2):

I also was faced with this issue using Xamarin

I asked Xamarin and currently there is no possibility to prevent it happening but they will add enhancement to make it so in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could either embed lldb with your project (as some projects embed git to avoid the same problem), or you could switch to a 3rd party crash reporter such as Crashlytics.

---

While the above may work in other cases, it seems that the best you can do is [submit a bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) to Apple.

Comment: Very interesting, could you please detail how to program my application to use my custom lldb when crashing? Redirecting crashes to a "dummy lldb" would be ideal. For instance a dummy lldb that just writes debugging information to a text file.

Comment: It all depends on how you call lldb. Maybe you're using the default search paths to get the command? Then you should specifically point the lldb inside your app bundle.

Comment: My program does not reference lldb in any way. I had no idea what lldb was, before I first got this popup message.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding why this would be considered an Apple bug.